# why doesn't this piece of code make a table?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am new to using c# and sqlite.

Why isn't this code working.
i tried it a little bit different. But had no success.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
        {
            con.Open();
            try
            {
                SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
                const string createTableQuery = @"CREATE TABLE User userName NOT NULL varchar(40), passWord NOT NULL varchar(40))";
                cmd.CommandText = createTableQuery;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (i == 1)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Table created");
                }
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            } 
        }

    }
```

Comment: Are you getting an error, or is it simply not behaving as you expect?

Comment: After your last edit you have a missing opening parenthesis between `User` and `userName`. Also, you execute the command twice. The second execution will fail in any case.

Comment: I changed it but it still says no connection associated with this command.

Answer (score 2):

you should execute the command

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            string createTableQuery = @"CREATE TABLE User (userName NOTNULL varchar(40), passWord NOTNULL varchar(40))";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = createTableQuery;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();//Here
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }  
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query is wrong:

```
    string createTableQuery = @"CREATE TABLE User (userName NOTNULL 
varchar(40), passWord NOTNULL varchar(40))";
```

It should be `NOT NULL` and not `NOTNULL`:

```
    string createTableQuery = @"CREATE TABLE User (userName NOT NULL
 varchar(40), passWord NOT NULL varchar(40))";
```

And then call:

```
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

after:

```
cmd.CommandText = createTableQuery;
```

Comment: Don't know it yet. Monday i can try it out on my pc. Will let you know.

Comment: it doesn't work this way. need your advise one more time :)

Answer (score 0):

The code is working in the sense that it does exactly what it seems like it should be doing. The issue is that you never actually run any query. You just wrote a letter and never put it in the mail-box and then wonder why it never arrived to the recipient.

The `SQLiteCommand` class has a method called `ExecuteNonQuery()` that you need to invoke in order for anything to actually happen.

Answer (score 0):

Execute your command:

```
try
        {
            string createTableQuery = @"CREATE TABLE User (userName NOTNULL varchar(40), passWord NOTNULL varchar(40))";
            SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = createTableQuery;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```